# MeteorJS mobile app push notification in background

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I am currently working on an mobile push notification (android) using MeteorJS. I am using the package:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

It works fine when the app is open but when closed nothing happens. Is there a way using this package to make the push notification works even when the app is closed or minimized? Is there an alternative package for meteor that can do background push notification? So far this is my code:

```
if(Meteor.isCordova){

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.registerPermission(function (granted) {
      if(confirm("Sample App would like to send you notifications: ") === true) {
        alert('permission granted '+granted)
      } else {
        alert('permission denied')
      }
    });

  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      var msg = $('[name=msg]').val();
      cordova.plugins.notification.local.add({ title: 'This is a sample push', message: msg });
    }
  });
};
```

A very straight forward code that works only when the app is open. I am clueless on how the background notification actually works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have not created a `schedule` for the notification yet. If the app isn't running, then the code you've written to execute the plugin won't be running either unless it's scheduled to do so, therefore creating a background process once the app has been loaded and permissions granted.

Change your initialization of the notification from:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.add({ 
    title: 'This is a sample push', 
    message: msg });
```

To:

```
date = foo; //change this to when you want the notification to fire 
            //for the first time

cordova.plugins.notification.local.**schedule**({
    id: 1,
    title: 'this is a sample push',
    message: msg,
    firstAt: date,
    every: 'minute' //set this to how often you want it repeated.
)};
```

What ended up happening is the template initialized the notification without any further parameters on how it is supposed to run. This is all thoroughly explained in the packages documentation if you need further help.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, I will try and play around with your solution.

Comment: No problem! Be sure to accept the answer if it ends up working for you, and good luck! :)

Comment: Hey @WebsiteIsFun, sorry for the late reply on this. If you haven't already figured this out, would you mind telling me what does happen when you attempt this with iOS?

Comment: actually iOS does not allow local notification, you have to use push notification to make it work in iOS so I just used raix push notifications to make it work on both ios and android